# What happens if you add your just created object to a mutable array and you release your object?

Tags: objective-c

What happens if you add your just created object to a mutable array and you release your object?

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you owned the object before adding it to the array, you still must release your own ownership claim to avoid a leak - the array's ownership claim on the object is separate, and does nothing to absolve you of your own responsibility with respect to the memory management rules.

```
Object *obj = [[Object alloc] init];
[anArray addObject:obj];
[obj release];
```

On the other hand, if you did **not** own the object, then you **still** don't own it after you add it to the array, and still must not release it. The array does establish its own ownership claim, but just like your own code, it's responsible for balancing its own claims.

```
Object *obj = [Object object];
[anArray addObject:obj];

// or, avoiding a temp variable

[anArray addObject:[Object object]];
```

When you release the array, or delete the object from the array (assuming it's a mutable array), the array will release its own ownership claim. The calling code has no added responsibility for that - the array made an ownership claim, so it's responsible for releasing it when it's done with the object.

In other words, your responsibility for releasing an object or not has **nothing** to do with whether you've added it to a collection. Nor does the array's responsibility have anything at all to do with what happens outside the array. That's at the heart of encapsulation; each class is as isolated as possible from what goes on inside of other classes. What happens in NSVegas, stays in NSVegas. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's ok:

```
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
  Object *obj = [[Object alloc] init];
  [array addObject:obj];
  [obj release];
```

I've created the object using `alloc, init` - so i'm the owner of the object. I've added the object into array and array became owner. Then i've released the object. But it still have an owner - the array.

By the way: If you will release array the object will released automatically.

Comment: Note that, since the array takes ownership of the object, a similar code that creates an object that’s not owned by the caller would work as well.

Comment: Also note that sending `-retain` to the mutable array isn’t necessary in this particular code snippet.

Comment: @Bavarious: If the object will not be owned by the caller it will be removed when calling [obj release] because it will have only 1 retain counter. In this case i think you will also have an bad access exception when releasing array.

Comment: That’s right, I’ve missed that ‘release your object’ part. You’re correct: although the object would still be alive because it’s owned by the array, there will be an exception when the array itself is released.

Comment: The point stands though. If there's a convenience method that returns an unowned object, this could could be simplified by using it, down to just `[array addObject:[Object object]]`. Yes, calling `-release` on the Object created this way would crash - so don't do that. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would allocate array this way:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array retain]

Object *obj = [[Object alloc] init]; //retain count = 1
```

When you add the object the retain count goes to +2

```
[array addObject:obj]; 

//When you release the retain count goes to 1 (object still exists)
[obj release];
```

If you release the array

```
[array release];
```

then the object count goes to 0.